# Is there a good way to block beta-reduction from automatically occurring in goals?

Tags: coq

Suppose you wish to prove `(fun (x : unit) => false) <> (fun (x : unit) => true)`.  The obvious way to prove this would be to `intro` some `H : (fun _ : unit => false) = (fun _ : unit => true)` and use `H` for a rewrite to prove that `false = (fun x => false) tt = (fun x => true) tt = true)`.  However, if you try to do this, Coq will automatically beta reduce and you will no longer have `(fun x => false)` and `(fun x => true)` as subterms with which you could rewrite with `H`.

The way I've gotten around this sort of issue is to define something like `app{X Y}(f : X -> Y)(x : X) := f x` and then using `app` to block the beta reduction.  However, this feels a bit hacky so I'm wondering if there's a nicer way to avoid these sorts of issues.

Comment: I would just use an auxiliary lemma `Lemma eq_f A B (f g : A -> B) : f = g -> forall x, f x = g x.`

Comment: Another way to solve this particular problem is to `apply (f_equal (fun f => f tt)) in H`.

Comment: What does your proof script look like? I cannot reproduce your problem -- everything works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there's a nicer way to avoid these sorts of issues

Coq blindly β reduces in many cases, and there is no good way to tell it not to.  (Worse, in my opinion, Coq assumes that it can always ζ-reduce, which can lead to exponential blow up at definition-time if you use a lot of `let`s.)

The solution I use to hide β-redexes is a bit more lightweight than yours; she has `id : forall {A}, A -> A` in the standard library, so I generally just wrap my λs in `id` when I want to block β-reduction.

A much, much, much more heavyweight solution is to use reflective automation like RTac that in principle gives you more fine-grained control, or to roll your own OCaml tactic library (or your own `rewrite`) that doesn't blindly β-reduce in subterms it doesn't touch.

A different-weight solution is to open a bug on the bug tracker that `rewrite` should not β-reduce in subterms it doesn't otherwise touch, and get a Coq dev to fix the problem for you.